# How should I use FETCH in MYSQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I am practicing with MySQL 8.0. I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( 
   EmpID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
   Name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   Address  varchar(255),
   Phone varchar(255),  
   Salary varchar(255)
);
```

I am trying to fetch using this code using OFFSET and FETCH:

```
SELECT Name, Address FROM Employees ORDER BY Salary OFFSET 2 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY;
```

But this error shows up:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY LIMIT 100' at line 1
```

I don't understand. Many websites use this method and it is not working for me.
For example (the site I referred):

educba: https://www.educba.com/mysql-fetch/

Comment: The site educba is wrong, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html   (The `OFFSET`,`NEXT` is (AFAIK) not supported in MySQL, in MySQL you can use `LIMIT`)

Comment: As far as I know MySql does not support the FETCH clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LIMIT and OFFSET, check mysql 8.0 manual for SELECT https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

Comment: This solves the issue. Thanks for your help.